# Loss Function does not decrease when positivity constraint is added

Tags: pytorch, image-recognition

I have tried coding up an autograd program in Pytorch to perform a reconstruction of an complex valued image. When I run the autograd normally, it produces a semi-accurate reconstruction of the image and the loss function steadily decreases, but the background of the image is off by a certain value, and changes from 0 to -0.2. However, when I tried to implement a positivity constraint on the angles, the loss function does not decrease at all after 1 iteration. May I ask about relevant reasons for this problem?

Comment: Hi @yes, welcome to the site. Can you please describe wha you mean with "angles" and how you implemented the positivity constraint?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.